# Row_Number() returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, rownum

This is my query,

```
SELECT top 100
    UPPER(COALESCE(A.DESCR,C.FULL_NAME_ND)) AS DESCR,
    COALESCE(A.STATE, (SELECT TOP 1 STATENAME 
                       FROM M_STATEMASTER 
                       WHERE COUNTRYCODE = B.CODE)) AS STATENAME,
    COALESCE(A.STATECD, (SELECT TOP 1 CODE 
                         FROM M_STATEMASTER 
                         WHERE COUNTRYCODE = B.CODE)) AS STATECD,
    COALESCE(A.COUNTRYCD, B.CODE) AS COUNTRYCODE
FROM 
    M_CITY A
JOIN 
    M_COUNTRYMASTER B ON A.COUNTRYCD = B.CODE
JOIN 
    [GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE] C ON  B.ALPHA2CODE = C.CC_FIPS
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE] Z 
            WHERE B.ALPHA2CODE=Z.CC_FIPS) 
ORDER BY 
    A.CODE
```

Perfectly working fine, but when I'm trying to get the `Row_number() over(order by a.code)` I'm getting the duplicate column multiple time.

e.g

```
SELECT top 100
    UPPER(COALESCE(A.DESCR,C.FULL_NAME_ND)) AS DESCR,
    COALESCE(A.STATE, (SELECT TOP 1 STATENAME 
                       FROM M_STATEMASTER 
                       WHERE COUNTRYCODE = B.CODE)) AS STATENAME,
    COALESCE(A.STATECD, (SELECT TOP 1 CODE 
                         FROM M_STATEMASTER 
                         WHERE COUNTRYCODE = B.CODE)) AS STATECD,
    COALESCE(A.COUNTRYCD, B.CODE) AS COUNTRYCODE
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.CODE) AS RN -- i made a change here
FROM 
    M_CITY A
JOIN 
    M_COUNTRYMASTER B ON A.COUNTRYCD = B.CODE
JOIN 
    [GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE] C ON  B.ALPHA2CODE = C.CC_FIPS
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE] Z 
            WHERE B.ALPHA2CODE=Z.CC_FIPS) 
ORDER BY 
    A.CODE
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM [GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE] Z 
            WHERE B.ALPHA2CODE = Z.CC_FIPS)
```

Another try, when I'm using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newid()) AS RN` it's taking logn time to execute.

Remember: `CODE` is the Pk of table `M_CITY` and there is no key in `[GEODATASOURCE-CITIES-FREE]` table.

Another thing: About JOIN(inner join), Join returns the matched Rows, right???

e.g:

```
table 1 with 20 rows,
table2 with 30 rows ,
table 3 with 30 rows
```

If I joined these 3 table on a certain key then the possibility of getting maximum rows is 20, am I right?

Comment: You could get anywhere between 0 and 20*30*30 = 18,000 rows.  It depends on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query doesn't work fine.  It just appears to.  The reason is that you are using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`, so an arbitrary set of 100 rows is returned.

When you add `ROW_NUMBER()`, the query plan changes . . . and the ordering of the result set changes as well.  I would suggest that you fix the original query to use a stable sort.

Comment: can you explain about the Join i mentioned in my question.

Comment: No. You could possibly get 20 x 30 x 30 = 18,000 rows, depends on the data you join on.

Comment: in Inner join?
like `select * from ta1 a join tab2 b on a.id=b.pid join tab3 c on b.cid=c.din`
@Nick.McDermaid

Comment: if id's are not unique, yes. If table 1 has 5 records with id=7 and table 2 has  10 records with id=7 and you join on id you get 50 records.